# Pandas UDF Function Takes Unusually Long to Complete on Big Data

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I'm new to PySpark and Pandas UDFs, I'm running the following Pandas UDF Function to jumble a column containing strings (For Example: an input '*Luke*' will result in '*ulek*')

```
pandas_udf("string")
def jumble_string(column: pd.Series)-> pd.Series:
  return column.apply(lambda x: None if x==None else ''.join(random.sample(x, len(x))).lower()) 

spark_df = spark_df.withColumn("names", jumble_string("names"))
```

On running the above function on a large dataset I've noticed that the execution takes unusually long.

I'm guessing the `.apply` function has something to do with this issue.

Is there anyway I can rewrite this function so it can effectively execute on a Big Dataset?
*Please Advise*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `.apply` method is not vectorized, the given operation is done by looping through the elements which slows down the execution as the data size becomes large.

For small sized data, the time difference is usually negligible. However, as the size increases, the difference starts to become noticeable. We are likely to deal with vast amount of data so time should always be taken into consideration.

You can read more about Apply vs Vectorized Operations [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/efficient-pandas-apply-vs-vectorized-operations-91ca17669e84).

Therefore I decided to use a list comprehension which did increase my performance marginally.

```
@pandas_udf("string")
def jumble_string(column: pd.Series)-> pd.Series:
  return pd.Series([None if x==None else ''.join(random.sample(x, len(x))).lower() for x in column])
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no implemented function in Spark that jumbles the strings in a column, so we are forced to resort to UDFs or Pandas UDFs.

Your solution is actually quite nice; perhaps we can improve it by removing the `.apply` method from the series and using only base Python on a string for each row.

```
@pandas_udf("string")
def jumble_string_new(column: pd.Series)-> pd.Series:
  x = column.iloc[0]   # each pd.Series is made only of one element
  if x is None:
    return pd.Series([None])
  else:
    return pd.Series([''.join(random.sample(x, len(x))).lower()])
```

The results are the same to your function; however, I've not been able to test it on a very large dataframe. Try it yourself and see whether it's computationally more efficient.

Comment: I'll definitely try this and get back to you

Comment: I tried running it on a dataset with 500 rows  using `spark_df.withColumn("first_name", shuffle_string("first_name"))` and got the error `PythonException: 'RuntimeError: Result vector from pandas_udf was not the required length: expected 500, got 1'`

Comment: You are getting this error because this kind of Pandas UDFs (SCALAR type) require a pd.Series as output, not a single string. Btw, what is `shuffle_string`? Where is it defined?

Comment: My bad, `shuffle_string` and `jumble_string` are the same

Comment: I tried my proposed `jumble_string_new` on a very small dataset and it worked smoothly. Are you sure that the input and output of the Pandas UDF are actually pd.Series?

Comment: Yup! I executed it on the same dataframe as `jumble_string`. Is `x = column.iloc[0]` causing the error?

Comment: `.iloc[0]` should take the first element of the Series. Since the Pandas UDF is applied to every row, it will take the element of that row

Comment: So your code is only designed to jumble the first row value in column? As opposed to the whole column?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236566/discussion-between-ric-s-and-luke).